# Change nickname from all servers getting the guilds ids

Tags: node.js, discord.js

there is any way to change the NICKNAME of the bot with the guilds ids in all the servers that the bot is (the bots has the perm to change nickname).

This is the code that I used to get the guilds ids but idk how to change the nickname in all the guilds using the ids.

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status:"online",
        activity: {
            name: "Loading....",
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    })
})


client.on("message", message => {

    const servers = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    console.log(servers);


})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this code will console log every Guild#id when a new message is getting received by the bot.

```
client.on("message", message => {

    const servers = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    console.log(servers);


})
```

I would recommend due to personal experience to map all guilds inside the `ready` event.

To change the nickname from the bot (You actually don't need mapping all guilds) you could do this by writing this code into your `ready` event:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    guild.me.setNickname(/* Nickname as a string */);
});
```

You should write this code into your ready event because if you write it just into the file you would try to change your nickname while you haven't even fetched all guilds from the API.

If you only want to do this after you executed a specific command, you can use the code from above and paste it into the command.

Reference:

- Personal experience
- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me

Comment: Okay, this is working on a message event and in the ready event, is possilbe to make it working in a function? because I need to change the nickname every 10 / 15 secs

Comment: Yes. But you can just put this into a `setInterval` with 10000 or 15000 as interval. Btw rapidly changing the nickname in a guild can result in rate limits

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible using `.setNickname` on a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.

First of all, you probably want to check you have permissions to do this using something like:

```js
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) return; // Bot doesn't have permission to change username
```

Then to actually set the bots nickname you can use:

```js
message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).setNickname("nickname");
```

However this will just change the nickname for the bot when a message comes in, if you wanted to do it for all guilds you could do something like:

```js
const servers = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
servers.forEach((id) => {
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(id);
    guild.members.get(client.user.id).setNickname("nickname");
});
```